# Custom Image Rotation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

How can I rotate these images clockwise? When they load they are on their side for some reason.

```
    //load the image
    API* api = [API sharedInstance];//afnetworking call
    int IdPhoto = [[data objectForKey:@"IdPhoto"] intValue];
    NSURL* imageURL = [api urlForImageWithId:[NSNumber numberWithInt: IdPhoto] isThumb:YES];
    AFImageRequestOperation* imageOperation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL] success:^(UIImage *image) {
        //create an image view, add it to the view
        UIImageView* thumbView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
        thumbView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,90,90);//thumbsize of image 180 is width and size 0 is spacing coordinates x,y
        thumbView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self insertSubview: thumbView belowSubview: caption];
    }];
    NSOperationQueue* queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue addOperation:imageOperation];
}

return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: I think it'll be much easier to rotate each imageView.  thumbView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*1.5); //or perhaps M_PI*0.5 for a quarter turn the other direction...

Comment: jef you are awesome; exactly what i needed. feel free to repost that as an answer instead of comment so i can accept it if you want ha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at just rotating the imageView like this:

```
thumbView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*1.5); //or perhaps M_PI*0.5 for a quarter turn the other direction...
```

because its much easier, altering the orientation on the image itself requires drawing it to a context somewhere in order to pull out a fresh data representation.